# Does Global Entry give you any benefits when flying GA?

Tags: international, pre-clearance

If I fly GA into Canada from the US or into the US from Canada, does having Global Entry give me any advantage? Can I taxi straight to the FBO or my tie down spot, or do I still have to taxi over to customs? Is there any ability to fly direct to a destination and not have to stop at a port of entry airport?

What is the difference between Pre clearance and Global Entry? Can you get pre clearance without having Global Entry?

Comment: You might try asking this on [travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/) as well; people there may be more knowledgeable about Global Entry

Comment: @Pondlife Yeah, they probably have more knowledge about Global Entry, but probably not as much about GA aspects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CBP](http://www.cbp.gov/travel) has a lot of programs. Government programs are confusing. Regarding the two you mention...

Global Entry basically expedites the Customs process for pre-approved travelers, making use of an automated kiosk. The service is available at [approved locations](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/locations), generally major aiports. <strike>Clearly</strike>Normally, this program is meant for the commercial traveler. However, large international GA destinations can have this service as well. Example: FLL, one of the nation's busiest international GA airports. [They have a global entry kiosk at their GA facility](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/travel-tourism/fort-lauderdale-hollywood-international-airport-fll).

[Preclearance](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/pleasure-boats-private-flyers) means that traveler processing/aircraft inspection are handled *before* the flight, rather than upon arrival in the US. But, this isn't very widespread yet. *Private aircraft* preclearance processing is only available at Shannon, Ireland and Oranjestad, Aruba. And the list of airports you can fly to, from what I have seen, is smaller than the list of Ports of Entry.

So no, neither of these programs really helps you out as a Canada/US travelling GA pilot. They aren't for small airports. You have to deal with [Customs, APIS, and Ports of Entry](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/us_restrictions/airspace/#entry), and [everything else](https://www.eapisfile.com/Docs/eAPIS/private_flyers_guide.pdf) :)

Comment: Great. Thanks for the detailed answer. I was having a lot of trouble finding information on these programs that applied to flying GA. I'll award you the bounty in 18 hours when SO let's me.